# Joomla Web page rel="canonical"

Tags: joomla, canonical-link

I need help  to modify this rel="canonical" below to automatically pick up the url of the page, I have    SEF turned on and using Joomla .htacces

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yourwebsite.com<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" />
```

this statement gets me the site's main url.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use: `JURI::current()`

In your code:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Good answer. It's usually best to use Joomla's API whenever possible.

Comment: @GerriJensen if it worked for you, please approve this answer by clicking the green icon next to it.